# How can I read the Bluetooth LE advertisement data in Android at the time of scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth

Bluetooth LE devices can broadcast messages to other devices. That message packet can include informations like length, profile, rssi (signal strength), etc.

How can I read those Bluetooth LE broadcast data when scanning for BLE devices in Android?

Comment: U can understand like that .. Bluetooth device contains some advertisement data that data contains its Mac-id,nameand the header part ... So I have to read that raw data

Comment: Are you talking about Bluetooth Low Energy (SMART) Advertising packets or Bluetooth BR/EDR paging/inquiry e.g Extended Inquiry messages?

Comment: yes Pev Iam talking about BLE advertising packets which contains some data..

Answer (score 8):

**API Levels 21+**

In  **android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback**, the callback method as follows has a parameter named **result**, which has a field called **scanRecord**, with should contain the advertisement data sent by a BLE device.

```
void onScanResult (int callbackType, ScanResult result)
```

**API Levels 18-20**

In **BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback**, the callback method as follows has a parameter named **scanRecord**, which should contain the advertisement data sent by a BLE device.

```
public abstract void onLeScan (BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord)
```

**scanRecord:** The content of the advertisement record offered by the remote device.