# How to get raw scan record (advertising packet) while scanning for classic bluetooth devices in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

What I'm doing now is trying to scan for both BLE and classic bluetooth devices at the same time. As far as I could see I can discover both by using:

`BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().startDiscovery()` and receiving intents via previously registered `BroadcastReceiver`. It works fine and I can distinguish between classic and LE devices but I have some valuable data in advertising packet and I have no idea how to get it from incoming `Intent`. Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22315225/1214974

Comment: onLeScan this is for BLE devices, but I need to get this `scanRecord` (advertisement packet) from classic device.

Comment: Sorry, I thought only BLE allowed bundling advertisement data. What is in the packet?

Comment: Where did you hear this? There is some device specific data (color,model, etc.), the issue actually is in getting this advertisement data for BLE device but scanning like for classic using `startDiscovery()` and receiving result in `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: I didn't hear it from somewhere/someone, I just never used bundling of extra advertisement data in Bluetooth Classic. I added an answer that may help you get some of the information you need. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this will allow you to get *all* the information you need, but it should allow you to get at least some of it.

When you receive the `ACTION_FOUND` `Intent`, that `Intent` has an extra field identified by `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE`. This extra contains an instance of `BluetoothDevice` that represents the remote device. The `BluetoothDevice` instance will allow you to get some information about the device such as its name and type.

Moreover, the `ACTION_FOUND` `Intent` also has an extra field identified by `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_CLASS` which contains a `BluetoothClass` instance that also provides some more information about the remote device such as the class of the device.

See the class documentation for [BluetoothDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html) and [BluetoothClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.html).

Comment: Yeah, I know that but unfortunately there is no extra in `Intent` for raw bytes that I need and also neither `BluetoothDevice` or `BluetoothClass` doesn't provide that too.