# I want to send text data through Ios to android using Bluetooth Low Energy Protocol through Advertisements

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to send text data through Ios to android using Bluetooth Low Energy Protocol through Advertisements. I have tried alot of code examples but nothing find useful. Please suggest me any working example so i can transmit data in connection less transmissions through advertisements from Ios to android and android to ios. please help my guys. I will be thankful to you !!!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is doable but you may need some digging and trial-and-error as there isn't any ready example that I am aware of. To achieve what you want, you have to:-

1. Send custom data from iOS via BLE advertisements.
2. Read the custom data from Android via BLE scanning.

You can achieve the first part through one of the examples below:-

- [Sending bluetooth LE data in advertisement on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128790/sending-bluetooth-le-data-in-advertisement-on-ios)
- [Custom BLE Advertisement on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772064/custom-ble-advertisement-on-ios)

And info on the second part can be found here:-

- [How can I read the Bluetooth LE advertisement data in Android at the time of scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733567/how-can-i-read-the-bluetooth-le-advertisement-data-in-android-at-the-time-of-sca)
- [Read advertisement packet in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003777/read-advertisement-packet-in-android)

Some other useful references:-

- [Ble: Send advertise data to iOS from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805222/ble-send-advertise-data-to-ios-from-android)
- [Ultimate Guide to Apple's Core Bluetooth](https://punchthrough.com/core-bluetooth-basics/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)
- [Ultimate Guide to Android BLE Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220159/location-needs-to-be-enabled-for-bluetooth-low-energy-scanning-on-android-10-0/58232014#58232014)